# how do you disable (or keep closed) a side panel in Chrome?

Tags: html

this program will automatically open the side panel when a row is clicked (not the Chrome Side Panel).  Looking for a way to keep it closed, and Development will not implement a way to turn this off.  Below is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="sidepanel-toggle-button active__sidepanel-open">
```

looking for the following to always be the case:

```
<div class="sidepanel-toggle-button active__sidepanel-close">
```

Comment: what?⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀